# ReactS3Client library 403 forbidden error on post to S3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the ReactS3Client and I am having issues with uploading to a bucket. I have all the config files ready. I am using a 3rd party library that allows a user to upload media to a designated cloud server, that being S3. Everything works good on iOS side for the configuration and I am able to upload accordingly. For that, I am using AmplifyCLI.

The error I am getting is: POST BUCKETURL 403 (Forbidden)

On the S3 side, I configured the following -- [S3 bucket policy config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeAQ6.png)

I know the error stems from the S3 CORS policy. Ive tried making the bucket public and editing the policy to allow all sorts of requests, but I'm still receiving the 403 forbidden error.

Any help would be really appreciated.